# Rebus RabbitMQ very slow publishing messages

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rebus

I have problem with performance during publishing messages by Rebus (Rabbitmq).

Here is little example:

```
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var command = new CreateExampleEmptyCommand();
            Debug.WriteLine("Sending command: " + i);
            await _bus.Send(command);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Debug.WriteLine("duration: " + elapsedMs);
```

Publishing of 1000 messages takes 9 seconds which gives 110 messages/second. The same value I can see on rabbitmq management page:

http://localhost:15672/#/queues/test/myqueue

110 messages/second is very slow, but I have no idea where is the reason.

Kind Regards !

Comment: How many messages can you publish if you are using the RabbitMQ driver directly?

Comment: What is the type of `_bus`?